# Why isn't my mock.assert_called_once() passing?

Tags: python, function, mocking, pytest

I have function 1 here:

```
def f1(x):
    f2(x+3)
    return x * x
```

And function 2 here:

```
def f2(y):
    print("Whatever you do, don't print this.")
```

I wrote my test here:

```
def test_f1(mocker):
    mock = mocker.patch("functions.f2")
    assert f1(1) == 1
    assert f2(1) is None
    mock.f2.assert_called_once()
```

When I run pytest, it throws the error:

```
>       mock.f2.assert_called_once()
E       AssertionError: Expected 'f2' to have been called once. Called 0 times.
```

I literally just called "f2" but it's not picking up on it? Not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

For a number of reasons:

1. `mocker.patch` returns the mock, so the mocked `f2` is `mock`, not `mock.f2`.
2. From the code you posted, it appears you have a line like

   ```
   from functions import f1, f2
   ```

   or

   ```
   from functions import *
   ```

   This means that if you monkey-patch `functions.f2`, *you are not monkey-patching your local variable `f2`*. `mock` is the same as the mocked `functions.f2`, but `f2` is no longer the same as `functions.f2` (because it's the original `functions.f2`, not the mocked one). You can fix this (along with problem #1) with code like:

   ```
   f2 = mocker.patch("functions.f2")
   # ...
   f2.assert_called_once()
   ```
3. Except now `assert f2(1) is None` will fail. This is because you mocked `f2`. That means the real `f2` isn't called. Did you mean to do a spy instead of a mock? With a spy, the real function is called. pytest-mock can handle spies, though you might need to change your imports slightly:

   ```
   import functions
   from functions import f1, f2

   def test_f2(mocker):
       f2 = mocker.spy(functions, 'f2')
       assert f1(1) == 1
       assert f2(1) is None
       f2.assert_called_once()
   ```
4. And now we finally...get a failed `assert_called_once()` again, this time because `f2` has been called twice. That's because it's called once when you call `f1(1)`, and then a second time when you call `f2(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're asserting that `mock.f2()` was done, not that `f2()` was done.

I'm not exactly clear on what kind of object your fixture `mocker` is, nor am I sure I understand what you actually want to do, but perhaps you want `mock.assert_called_once()`? You can also check `mock.mock_calls()`.

Comment: `mocker` is a fixture provided by the pytest-mock plugin: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/. It's a patch wrapper. It's pretty useful.

Comment: yes, mock.assert_called_once() works and my test passes. I want to ensure my function "f2" was called (not the print statement, I want to test the call parameters not the value) im not sure how to do that. i was trying to assert my "f2" function was called

Comment: Oh, I see. I usually just use the stdlib unit test patch and mock functionality directly. Anyways looks like you're supposed to use `spy` instead? If I'm correctly guessing what you're trying to do.

Comment: i dont think i have to spy. when i pass 1 to f(1), im not sure whats passed to f(2)? is it also 1?